# physicsbody from image texture not working

Tags: xcode, swift, skphysicsbody

i have the following line of code you can see below:

```
Enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: player.texture, size: player.size)
```

when i try to run this code i get the following error:

```
Value of optional type 'SKTexture ?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'
```

can someone tell me what i am doing wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The init method `SKPhysicsBody(texture: player.texture, size: player.size)` takes a `SKTexture` instance as opposed to an `Optional<SKTexture>` (aka. `SKTexture?`) instance which you provided. So the `player.texture` needs to be unwrapped.

Assuming you know you've loaded your texture correctly and it is not `nil`:

```
Enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: player.texture!, size: player.size)
```

Or to safely unwrap the texture:

```
if let texture = player.texture {
  Enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: texture, size: player.size)
}
```